# How to create option list from array using add method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use the following for loop but still showing one option.

```
var x = document.getElementById("cars");
var option = document.createElement("option");
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    option.text = "BMW";
    x.add(option);
}
```

Comment: try to move createElement inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initiate `createElement` variable inside the loop

```
var x = document.getElementById("cars");
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "BMW";
    x.add(option);
}
```